# How to set Template in asp.net from cs file?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Is it possible to set ITemplate property of the control in cs file ?

In aspx file I can do it by for example:

```
<MyControl>
    <MyTemplate>
        <div>
        sample text, other controls
        </div>
    </MyTemplate>
</MyControl>
```

this div in real situation looks like this:

```
<div id="StatusBarDiv" runat="server" align="right">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <dxe:ASPxLabel ID="Title" runat="server" Text="Records per page:">
                </dxe:ASPxLabel>
            </td>                    
            <td>
                <dxe:ASPxComboBox ID="cbxRecordsPerPage" ClientInstanceName="cbxRecordsPerPage" Width="50px" runat="server" SelectedIndex="<%#GetSelectedIndex()%>">
                    <Paddings PaddingBottom="0" PaddingTop="0" />
                    <Items>
                        <dxe:ListEditItem Text="10" Value="10" />
                        <dxe:ListEditItem Text="20" Value="20" />
                        <dxe:ListEditItem Text="30" Value="30" />
                        <dxe:ListEditItem Text="40" Value="40" />
                        <dxe:ListEditItem Text="50" Value="50" />
                    </Items>
                </dxe:ASPxComboBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed possible. You can assign an instance of a class implementing [ITemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.itemplate.aspx) to your template property in your code-behind file:

```
public class YourTemplate: ITemplate
{
    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        div.InnerText = "sample text, other controls";
        container.Controls.Add(div);
    }
}
```

Then, in your `MyControl` class:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    MyTemplate = new YourTemplate();
}
```

**EDIT:** Since the content of your template is quite complex, it would not be very convenient to create its control tree by hand, as I did in the example above.

It would probably be best to host the control tree in a [user control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53.aspx) and load that control in the template using the [LoadControl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ecy7tf.aspx) method:

```
public class YourTemplate: ITemplate
{
    public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
    {
        Control userControl = container.Page.LoadControl("YourUserControl.ascx");
        container.Controls.Add(userControl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats what Im talking about, I will check it if its ok I will return here :)

Comment: Hi, container.Page is Null :/

Comment: @gruber, that's strange, your wrapper control (the `MyControl` instance) should already have been added to the page by the time the template is instantiated. Is that control defined in your page markup or do you add it by code?